# Removing trailing 0s from a String formatted decimal / Java error - Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near index 15

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match the last set of 0s in a decimal. Eg: In `9780.56120000` `0000` would be matched. This regex:

`(?<=\.\d{0,20})0*$`

seems to work in RegexBuddy but Java fails with the following error:

> Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near
>   index 15

Can anyone provide some insight into this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification edits, Perception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java is interpreting `{0,20}` as being "unbounded", which it doesn't support.

Why do you need a look behind? Use a non-capturing group instead:

```
(?:\.\d*)0*$
```

#### Edited:

To remove trailing zeros from decimal numbers in a String, use this single line:

```
input.replaceAll("(\\.(\\d*[1-9])?)0+", "$1");
```

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "trim 9780.56120000 and 512.0000 but not this00, 00 or 1234000";
    String trimmed = input.replaceAll("(\\.(\\d*[1-9])?)0+", "$1");
    System.out.println(trimmed);
}
```

Output:

```
trim 9780.5612 and 512. but not this00, 00 or 1234000
```

#### Edited again:

If you want to handle when there are only trailing zeros to also remove the decimal point, ie `"512.0000"` becomes `"512"`, but `"123.45000"` still retains the decimal point ie `"123.45"`, do this:

```
String trimmed = input.replaceAll("(\\.|(\\.(\\d*[1-9])?))0+\\b", "$2");
```

More test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "trim 9780.56120000 and 512.0000 but not this00, 00 or 1234000";
    String trimmed = input.replaceAll("(\\.|(\\.(\\d*[1-9])?))0+\\b", "$2");
    System.out.println(trimmed);
}
```

Output:

```
trim 9780.5612 and 512 but not this00, 00 or 1234000
```

Comment: Because that matches more than just `0000` it matches everything after the decimal. I need to replace the `0000` with an empty string. How can I bound it?

Comment: So you want to delete trailing zeros from decimal numbers in a String?

Comment: Worth noting that this will not match a string like `512.0000` or anything else with nothing but 0s after the decimal.

Comment: @KevinMark fixed the regex to cater for only zeros after the decimal point. See edited answer with tweaked regex. See further edit for special dealing with dangling decimal points, ie `"512.0000"` being trimmed to `"512"` not `"512."`

Comment: Perfection, @Bohemian. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @KevinMark no worries. not wanting to grovel for points or anything, but if you wanted to show extra appreciation, you can always donate extra reputation points by starting a bounty and awarding the bounty to this answer :) No pressure :D

Comment: I'll add a bounty as soon as I can. I appreciate the follow up edits.

Comment: @KevinMark Thanks for the bounty! Much appreciated (it helped me make 200 for the day... one step closer to [Legendary](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary) :) )

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using regular expressions at all and decided to just loop through each character of the decimal starting at the end and working backwards. Here's the implementation I used. Thanks to Bohemian for pushing me in the right direction.

```
if(num.contains(".")) { // If it's a decimal
    int i = num.length() - 1;
    while(i > 0 && num.charAt(i) == '0') {
        i--;
    }
    num = num.substring(0, i + 1);
}
```

Code based off the `rtrim` function found here: http://www.fromdev.com/2009/07/playing-with-java-string-trim-basics.html

**Edit:** And here's something to remove the decimal for this solution.

```
// Remove the decimal if we don't need it anymore
// Eg: 4.0000 -> 4. -> 4
if(num.substring(num.length() - 1).equals(".")) {
        num = num.substring(0, num.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Can I get some justification for the down vote, please? It's a possible solution I came up with. Not necessarily the best and I think I made that clear with the up vote, acceptance, and bounty on the other answer.